# Visual Studio import backlogs items details

Tags: excel, visual-studio, tfs, backlog

I'm importing Backlogs items from [Excel into Visual Studio Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&rd=true&l=FR-FR&k=k(vs.tfc.office.excelworkitems)). But I don't know how to add a column in Excel to be the backlog item "detail" (First I set the Item title, which is fine...).

(In Excel I'm using the "Team Explorer for Visual Studio", which provide me the "Team" menu in the upper ribbon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Excel ribbon click the <kbd>Choose Columns</kbd> item to configure which fields are available:

[image]

From the list look up the Description field and add it:

[image]

Now you can set the value in the column of the Excel file.

This is the way you can configure most columns (some may be read-only).